# How to approach and resolve this problem?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given $h(x,y)=f(x,y,z(x,y) )$

prove that:

[here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPOds.png)

$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}  \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}  \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$

i have problems getting the differentiation of z component to solve it.

Comment: Write h(x,y)=f(u,v,z) where u,v,z are functions of x and y. Differeniate the left side with respect to x by the chain rule. Now put u=x, v=y. Then do the same for y.

Answer (score 1):

The partial derivative means that you take the derivative of the functions to all its variables on which is depends explicitly. As an example, say we have $k(x) = x^2$, with $x(t) = 4t$. The partial derivative $\partial k/ \partial x = 2x$, but $\partial k/\partial t = 0$, since $k$ does not explicitly depend on $t$. In your case, we have a function $h(x,y)$ which depends explicitly on $x$ and $y$, so in the partial derivative you have to derive to those 2 variables. In order to do so, you need to use the chain rule, because $f$ depends on $z$ and $z$ depends on $x$ and $y$. I think this is enough as a proof, hope it made it more clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand\p[2]{{\partial{#1}\over\partial{#2}}}$
For example, let's say that $h(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z$ and $z(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ then
$$
\begin{align}
f(x,y)
&=h(x,\;y,\;z(x,y))\\
&=x^2+y^2\;+\;x^2+y^2\\
&=2x^2+2y^2,\\
\end{align}
$$
so
$$
\begin{align}
\p{h}{x}&=2x\\
\p{h}{y}&=2y\\
\p{h}{z}&=1\\
\end{align}
$$ but
$$
\begin{align}
\p{f}{x}&=4x\\
&=\p{h}{x}+\p{h}{z}\p{z}{x}\\
&=2x+2x.\\
\end{align}
$$